# Division of 2 values in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, count, pivot

Hello I'm a newbie in SQL.

I have a table of workers and I want to calculate the avg num of female workers.
I want to divide 2 tables that I create,  but when I do the division the value of the new table is NULL and the other is 0.

```
SELECT COUNT(SEX) AS NUMOFWOMEN
FROM project_2.stuff
WHERE SEX = WOMAN;

SELECT COUNT(SEX) AS TOTALNUMOFWORKERS
FROM project_2.stuff;

SELECT (CAST(NUMOFWOMEN AS FLOAT) / CAST(TOTALNUMOFWORKERS AS FLOAT)) * 100 AS avgnum;

SELECT CAST(avgnum AS FLOAT) AS AVGNUMOFWOMEN
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff It was a formatting fail.

Comment: I also did it with from but it had same values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to compute the ratio of rows where `sex = 'woman'` over your whole dataset, you can just use `avg()`:

```
select avg(sex = 'woman') as women_ratio
from project_2.stuff
```

Rationale: MySQL evaluates expression `sex = 'woman'` as `1` if the condition succeeds, else `0`. Averaging this value over the whole table gives you the result you want - you can multiply that by `100` if you want a percentage.

Note that there is no need to convert to `float` or the-like. MySQL happily takes decimal average of integers.